# Can someone put some restriction to copy few files from folder by root in linux

Tags: linux, unix, shell, root

I have the backup script where i was making the tar backup of directory everyday.
ON friday i note that my filesize was 30MB but beofrethat it was 200MB. I checked the main folder and it was around 200MB.

But everytime i backup that folder now even with root the size is same. But actual size is 200.

Is there any settings i can check

EDIT:

Just one line

```
 tar -czpf abc.tar.gz /home/jax/public_html/mysite/
```

Comment: Show us the script

Comment: You have gzip compression enabled (-z).  That could easily explain why the tar file is a lot smaller, depending on the contents of the archived directory.

Comment: i had that enabled before as well . The whole size is around 500MB , gzip size is about 200mb , but its only coming 40mb.

Comment: What changed in the file hierarchy on the day the tarball got smaller?

Comment: Are you getting any error messages?  Have you verified that the 30MB backup is valid and complete?